# Populate UILabel with JSON Data and encode URL

Tags: ios, json, swift

First of all, I need to encode the JSON url with a previous var `pasarid` value and then I need to get that JSON data and populate some UILabels. This is my code. I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

```
var pasarid = ""
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()


@IBOutlet weak var completo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var historia: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var año: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var estilo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var direccion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var director: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titulares: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/json/get_templos.php?id=(pasarid value here)").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

        if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["templos"].arrayObject {
            self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
}

        var dict = self.arrRes
        self.completo.text = dict["nombre"]
```

I am getting an error in the last line that says

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String: AnyObject]]' with an index of type 'String'

My JSON output is

```
{ "templos": [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "S. I. Catedral Basílica de la Encarnación",
    "descripcion": "Se encuentra dentro de los límites que marcaba la desaparecida muralla árabe sobre el solar de la primitiva mezquita aljama, el lugar donde los Reyes Católicos Isabel y Fernando ordenaron erigir un templo cristiano a los pocos días de conquistar la ciudad en 1487.\r\n\r\nSe caracteriza por tener una de las dos torres incompleta, popularmente haciendolo llamar entre los malagueños como la \"manquita\".",
    "antiguedad": "1782",
    "estilo": "Arquitectura Renacentista",
    "calle": "Calle Molina Lario, 9, 29015",
    "latitud": "36.7201678",
    "longitud": "-4.419310600000017",
    "director": "Sr. Obispo, Mons. Jesús Catalá Ibáñez",
    "titulares": "En el Sagrario de la Santa Iglesia Catedral se encuentra el Santísimo Cristo Mutilado.",
    "horario": "Santa Iglesia Catedral:\r\n\r\n · Horarios de apertura\r\n -De lunes a viernes: de 9 a 19 h.\r\n -Sábados: de 9 a 20 h.\r\n -Domingos: de 8:30 a 20 h.\r\n\r\n · Misas\r\n -De lunes a sábado: 9:15 h. con rezo de Laudes\r\n -Vísperas de domingos y de festivos: 19 h.\r\n -Domingos y festivos: 9, 10, 11:30, 13 y 19 h.\r\n\r\n · Confesiones\r\n -Media hora antes de cada misa\r\n    -Visitas concertadas en taquilla\r\n    De lunes a viernes: de 10 a 18 h.\r\n    Sábados: de 10 a 17 h.\r\n    -Visitas no concertadas\r\n    Domingos: de 14 a 18 h.\r\n\r\nSagrario de la Catedral:\r\n\r\n · Horarios de apertura\r\n -De lunes a viernes: de 10:15 a 12:15 h. y de 18 a 19 h.\r\n -Sábados: de 10:15 a 12:15 h.\r\n -Domingos: de 9:30 a 13:30 h.\r\n\r\n · Misas\r\n -De lunes a viernes: 10:30, 11:30 y 18:30 h.\r\n -Sábados: 10:30 y 11:30 h.\r\n \r\n · Confesiones\r\n -Media hora antes de cada misa\r\n\r\n · Bodas\r\n -Sábados por la tarde\r\n\r\n · Visitas no concertadas\r\n -Domingos: de 9:30 a 13:30 h."
    }
    ],
    "success": 1
    }
```

Comment: You've stated your goal, and posted some code. So what's wrong with your code? How does it not meet your goals? Does it fail to compile? Crash at runtime? Give the wrong results? Be specific.

Comment: Updated, thanks for your advice @DuncanC

Comment: `arrRes` is an array of dictionaries, but then you do `var dict = self.arrRes` and you try to access it like a dictionary. This is your issue.

Comment: its because your `arrRes` is an array of dictionary so you cannot access it using key value

Comment: can you post you `JSON`

Comment: How can I fix it? @EricD

Comment: My JSON data? @HamzaAnsari

Comment: We don't need your actual JSON values if they are confidential, but indeed showing your JSON *structure* with an example would help, Hamza is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use json result and populate your label as:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/json/get_templos.php?id=(pasarid value here)").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["templos"].array {
               self.completo.text = resDate[0]["nombre"].string
             }
})
```

Comment: what url i dont see any url in your ques?

Comment: The one I am getting JSON from

Comment: I don't know how to do it